# Show image from byte[] on CSHTML via javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm creating a timeline page with data from database, and I want to show a image from the object in the View.
The method Get it's working fine, when it returns the var imgSrc receives the data from the byte array converted to base64, but when I try to use the var in the  it shows undefinied when I inspect the page.

Someone can give me a hand on how can I solve this?

```
$.getJSON("../ReportsAuditsTimeLine/GetAuditsResultbyAudit", { AuditID: ID },
         function (data) {
        
             var datafromaudit = '';
             var div = document.createElement('div');
             $('#timeLine').empty();

             for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
             {
                 var base64 = "";
                 var imgSrc = "";

                 if (data[i].AUDIT_PICTURE != null)
                 {
                     //CHECK IMAGE

                     try {
                         base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(data[i].AUDIT_PICTURE);
                         imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", base64);
                         console.log("Imagem:", imgSrc);
                         
                     }
                     catch (Exception) {

                     }
                     //END IMAGE
                    
                 }

                 if (data[i].AUDIT_ITEM_STATUS == "PASS") {
                     if (data[i].AUDIT_PICTURE != null) {
                         datafromaudit += '<li><i class="fa fa-camera bg-green"></i> ' +
                                     '<div class="timeline-item">' +
                                     '<span class="time">' +
                                     '</span>' +
                                     '<h3 class="timeline-header"><b>ID:' + data[i].ID + "  - " + data[i].DESCRIPTION +
                                        '</b></h3>' +
                                      '<div class="timeline-body"> WEIGHT:       <b>' + data[i].OD + '</b>      STATUS:     <b style=color:green;>' + data[i].AUDIT_ITEM_STATUS + '</b>' + '<img src="' + $.imgSrc + '"class="margin" ></img>' + ' </div>' +
                                      '<div class="timeline-footer"/>'
                         '</div></li>'
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         datafromaudit += '<li><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o bg-green"></i> ' +
                                     '<div class="timeline-item">' +
                                     '<span class="time">' +
                                     '</span>' +
                                     '<h3 class="timeline-header"><b>ID:' + data[i].ID + "  - " + data[i].DESCRIPTION +
                                        '</b></h3>' +
                                      '<div class="timeline-body"> WEIGHT:       <b>' + data[i].OD + '</b>      STATUS:     <b style=color:green;>' + data[i].AUDIT_ITEM_STATUS + '</b>'  + ' </div>' +
                                      '<div class="timeline-footer"/>'
                         '</div></li>'
                     }
                 }
```

}

CONTROLLER

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public JsonResult GetAuditsResultbyAudit(string AuditID)
        {
            
                var viewModel = new ReportsAuditTimeLineViewModel();
                int auditID = Int32.Parse(AuditID);
                var auditResults = viewModel.GetAuditsResultbyAudit(auditID);
                return Json(auditResults, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            

        }
```

VIEWMODEL

```
 public List<AuditsResultData> GetAuditsResultbyAudit(int AuditID)
        {
            var list = new List<AuditsResultData>();


            var context = new OnlineAuditsEntities();
                using (context)
                {
                    var query = from audits in context.tb_Audits
                                join i in context.tb_AuditItem on audits.AUDIT_ITEM_ID equals i.ID                               
                                join a in context.tb_Audit on audits.AUDIT_ID equals a.ID                                
                                join s in context.tb_Audit_ItemStatus on audits.STATUS_ID equals s.ID
                                
                                where audits.AUDIT_ID == AuditID
                                select new { audits, i,a,s};
                    foreach (var s in query)
                    {
                    var Photo = (from pic in context.tb_AuditPictures
                                   where pic.AUDIT_ID == s.audits.ID
                                   select  pic.PICTURE).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (Photo!=null)
                        {
                            list.Add(new AuditsResultData
                            {
                                ID = s.audits.ID,
                                AUDIT_ITEM_ID = s.audits.AUDIT_ITEM_ID,
                                DESCRIPTION = s.i.SUBCATEGORY_DESCRIPTION,
                                HASFIND = s.i.HAS_FINDING ?? false,
                                FINDS = s.audits.FINDINGS ?? 0,
                                STATUS_ID = s.audits.STATUS_ID,
                                AUDIT_ITEM_STATUS = s.s.STATUS_DESCRIPTION,
                                OD = s.audits.OD ?? 0,
                                COMMENTS = s.audits.COMMENTS,
                                SCANS = s.audits.SCANNED_CODE,
                                AUDIT_ID = s.audits.AUDIT_ID,
                                AUDIT_PICTURE = Photo

                            });

                        }
                    }
                }        
            
            return list;
      
        }
```

Comment: Can you show your GetAuditsResultbyAudit method?

Comment: Updated the post with the Controller and the ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

You should pass picture to view as Base64String from controller. Then convert it to picture like:

```
var picture = "data:image/jpg;base64," + data.base64image;
```

Comment: I've changed my controller, created a new method which returns the file and it works. But now I have another problem between CSHTML and JS, but it's suitable for another topic. Thanks for your help